# How can I set system-wide defaults on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

We are currently updating some lab machines that are running Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala). What I'd like to know is if there is some way to set up the system's defaults (for instance which applications are present in the initial drop down menu or what applications are loaded on startup) but for every user, not just a specific profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, the menu items are populated from `/usr/share/applications`, so you can add new .desktop files there. As far as removing, I would just remove the package containing the program you don't want to show.

You can also look in `/etc/xdg/autostart` and `/etc/xdg/menus`.

Comment: Further inquiries led to the /etc/skel directory, which can be used to add files that are to be copied automatically. You can, for instance, add files to the Desktop folder.

Comment: Yes, good point, but note that /etc/skel only applies to _new_ accounts, so pushing new items in there into existing accounts will need to be something that is managed manually.